# Can the [a-zA-Z] Python regex pattern be made to match and replace non-ASCII Unicode characters?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

In the following regular expression, I would like each character in the string replaced with an 'X', but it isn't working.

In Python 2.7:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(u"[a-zA-Z]","X","dfäg")
'XX\xc3\xa4X'
```

or

```
>>> re.sub("[a-zA-Z]","X","dfäg",re.UNICODE)
u'XX\xe4X'
```

In Python 3.4:

```
>>> re.sub("[a-zA-Z]","X","dfäg")
'XXäX'
```

Is it possible to somehow 'configure' the [a-zA-Z] pattern to match 'ä', 'ü', etc.? If this can't be done, how can I create a similar character range pattern between square brackets that would include Unicode characters in the usual 'full alphabet' range? I mean, in a language like German, for instance, 'ä' would be placed somewhere close to 'a' in the alphabet, so one would expect it to be included in the 'a-z' range.

Comment: Use `\w`, it should suffice.

Comment: If I am understanding the question correctly, `\w` will exclude any letters which are not within the set `[A-Za-z]`. I've tried it [here](https://regex101.com/r/rR2hZ1/1).

Comment: @npinti: With the unicode modifier, [it matches the accented letter](https://regex101.com/r/rR2hZ1/2).

Comment: @stribizhev: Interestingly enough, using `\w` with the `u` flag changes `\w` from meaning `[A-Za-z0-9_]` to something else which includes `\p{L}`. Oddly enough `\p{L}` does not seem to be supported on its own in Python.

Comment: @DhaLee: Not a problem, you can use `(?![\d_])\w`.

Comment: @DhaLee: `\w` with the Unicode flag does what you are after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```py
(?![\d_])\w
[^\W\d_]
```

If used in Python 2.x, the `re.U` / `re.UNICODE` modifier is necessary. The `(?![\d_])` look-ahead is restricting the `\w` shorthand class so as it could not match any digits (`\d`) or underscores. The `[^\W\d_]` pattern matches any word char other than digits and underscores.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rR2hZ1/3).

A [Python 3 demo](https://ideone.com/o0WzHT):

```
import re
print (re.sub(r"(?![\d_])\w","X","dfäg"))
# => XXXX

print (re.sub(r"[^\W\d_]","X","dfäg"))
# => XXXX
```

As for [Python 2](http://ideone.com/kYgfmf):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
s = "dfäg"
w = re.sub(ur'(?![\d_])\w', u'X', s.decode('utf8'), 0, re.UNICODE).encode("utf8")
print(w)
```

Comment: Just a note: on Windows, in Python 2.x, the `# coding: utf-8` instruction can be added to enforce UTF8 encoding for the source.